Should I take the address of an array when using placement new?
If I have an array that's being used as a buffer for placement new:
alignas(T) unsigned char buf[sizeof(T)];

Then both uses of placement new will put a T into the buffer:
new (buf) T;
new (&buf) T;

But I take the address of the array in the second example, making a pointer to the entire array instead of a pointer to the first element.
Which usage is correct?

Probably doesn't matter. (1) looks more familiar, and it's also the only option when the array is heap-allocated.

That's what I thought, but I was unsure since I saw both versions being used. I thought there might be something obscure about array-to-pointer conversion.

@HeliumHydride I think most uses of &array that you see in real code are mistakes (though sometimes harmless mistakes). The genuine case for this construct is rare indeed.

@HeliumHydride   Not really.   In both your usages, the placement argument (buf or &buf) is implicitly converted to void * and passed as the second argument to a function operator new(std::size_t, void *) which simply returns its second argument (after which the pointed-to memory is initialised as a T). Since buf and &buf point to the same address (only their types differ) (void *)buf and (void *)&buf are equal.    So, in this case at least, using buf or &buf are equally correct.  [Stylistically, most folks prefer buf over &buf in this case].


Which usage is correct?

Both are correct. The address of the array, and the address of the 1st element of the array, are guaranteed to be the same address. Placement-new doesn't care how you get that address.
